# Respostas que contém informações difíceis de encontrar

Tags: debate, fechamento, exclusão

Alguns dias atrás, escreveram esta pergunta:

[Que códigos o webservice para cotação de moedas do Banco Central aceita?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54515/12)

Ela trata de como, e onde, conseguir informações sobre um webservice que está mal documentado. Foi fechada como fora de escopo, por realmente não estar relacionada a um problema de programação.

Algum tempo depois o próprio autor respondeu a pergunta, contando que teve que entrar em contato com o Banco Central Brasileiro para conseguir as informações que precisava para usar o webservice.

Hoje os moderadores passaram um tempo tentando decidir o que fazer com a pergunta, mas não chegamos a conclusão alguma:

### Lado A

- A pergunta não tem um problema técnico, mas sim de falta de documentação do webservice.
- Ninguém seria capaz de resolver esse problema a não ser que tivesse passado pelo mesmo processo e obtido acesso prévio à tabela pedida pelo autor.

Por esse lado, a pergunta efetivamente não pertence ao site.

### Lado B

- A solução para o problema é um tanto difícil de se conseguir, e isso a torna um recurso valioso para a comunidade.
- Essa solução é essencial para diversas outras pessoas que utilizam esse webservice.

O esses contrapontos não nos convenceram totalmente de que são suficientes para manter a pergunta no site. Então a questão é:

Desconsiderando os problemas de clareza e escrita da pergunta, que podem ser facilmente consertados a pergunta é:

O que fazer com problemas pouco ou nada técnicos, mas cuja solução é muito difícil de se obter?

---

Screenshot da resposta, para quem não tem reputação suficiente para enxergar conteúdos excluídos (ela foi excluída [pela fila de análise de baixa qualidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26694)):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entendo que uma tabela de códigos de um webservice é um problema de programação, como vários outros que temos que não dizem respeito ao código em si. Bem diferente de como baixar da internet determinado editor de código ou configurar a cor de fundo do notepad++. A tabela (ou a parte que influencia na lógica que a aplicação vai usar) é parte integral do código final da aplicação, inclusive. Quanto à resposta, me parece que é ajustável o "fator spam" dela para um formato de "crédito" facilmente. Eu só não vou votar para reabrir e restaurar a resposta pra aguardar o desenrolar da discussão.

Comment: Um argumento contra a pergunta é que ela poderia ser considerada um pedido de link, e produzir respostas link-only, mas isso seria simples de resolver com uma edição: "onde conseguir" pode ser substituído por "quais códigos de moeda esse serviço aceita". Perguntar isso seria como perguntar quais os parâmetros aceitos pela função X na linguagem ou biblioteca Y. E perguntas desse tipo costumam ser aceitas, mesmo quando a resposta é fácil de achar em documentação amplamente conhecida (como a MSDN).

Comment: Update: editei a resposta e votei para restauração, se a comunidade aprovar e restaurar, fica só a discussão sobre reabrir a pergunta ou não.

Comment: Com a edição que o bfavaretto sugeriu da pergunta, mais a edição da resposta do Bacco acho que ficaria bem aberta. Quanto a pergunta do Gabe, depende da pergunta, o melhor a fazer é mesmo abrir aqui um post no meta.

Comment: O salvamento dessa pergunta, que para mim não tinha jeito, me faz ver que a comunidade está caminhando bem. Esta é *uma pequena questão para o site, mas um grande avanço para a comunidade*. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bom... Esclarecendo as perguntas. Não! esse não é um problema específico e não foi eu que desenvolvi o webservice. O que eu quis compartilhar foi uma informação específica de um serviço público mantido pelo BC. Qualquer um algum dia pode precisar elaborar um serviço para pegar a cotação do dólar (ou outra moeda) de uma fonte confiável e que seja gratuito. Então segue meus argumentos para fazer o post:

1. Este é um webservice público. Quando estava fazendo o serviço vi que muitas pessoas tinham essa dúvida. Geralmente elas consomem um serviço de um site como infomoney ou outro.
2. A documentação para utilizar o webservice do Banco Central é fácil de achar. Uma pesquisa rápida no google você acha um tutorial ensinando. Agora quero ver alguém achar um link dentro do site do banco central que informe como conseguir a cotação de venda do dólar (por exemplo). O código 1 é cotação de compra, o 2 ouro, e por aí vai. Não é uma sequência lógica.
   Essa foi uma situação que passei no trabalho e como foi um pouco difícil achar a correspondência dos códigos resolvi compartilhar aqui
3. Spam para blog. Na moral, não preciso disso. Se vocês acessarem a raiz do blog vão ver que atualmente tem apenas um post. Outro detalhe, não tenho nenhum banner no blog (nem no meu site), então para quê eu ia querer visitas?
   Na verdade eu tive a ideia de criar o blog porque vou postar outros temas do cotidiano que acredito que possa ajudar outras pessoas. SSIS não é um tema tão difundido como asp net mvc, php, java etc.
   Se não ficou bem explicado blz, posso editar o post sem problemas e remover o link, mas a ideia não é ensinar a consumir o serviço, por isso, coloquei o link para o blog para não misturar os temas.

Comment: Creio que o ponto 3 é desnecessário agora, dei uma editada nela para deixar em evidência a tabela, que é o ponto importante da pergunta e da resposta, e o link para o blog continua lá (acho justo que fique, se é uma informação complementar), só deixei um pouco mais discreto, dê uma espiada e se puder, comente aqui o que acha.

Comment: @Bacco só foi considerado spam porque era um blog dele, se fosse um blog alheio estaria lá ainda...

Comment: @JorgeB. Apesar de justificar um pouco, o link pertencer ou não ao autor da resposta não é uma boa heurística pra justificar a sinalização como spam.

Comment: Sim @Gabe, para mim não é spam. Sendo ou não do autor. Neste caso, claro. Eu só estava a dizer que o pessoal sinalizou como spam por ser dele. Eu não sinalizava.

Comment: Tiago, a pergunta está reaberta e a resposta foi restaurada.

Comment: Vou dar uma melhorada na resposta e colocar o endereço do webservice que o BC disponibiliza e a descrição de todos os métodos desse webservice. Assim ficará mais fácil de associar a utilização dos códigos que disponibilizei com os métodos do WS.

Answer (score 6):

Como toda a resposta da comunidade até o momento foi favorável à reabertura, está feito. Fiz uma pequena edição antes, fiquem à vontade para melhorar se quiserem. Também desfiz a exclusão da resposta.